# Рендер совокупности стейтов

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

Первый раз делаю мини-проект на реакте - сайт с пиццей, столкнулся с такой проблемой:

У меня есть несколько видов сортировок, на каждую сортировку свой стейт. Чтобы отрендерить на странице карточки с пиццами я пробегаюсь по массиву data, где есть все карточки. И вот вопрос: во что можно объединить все стейты сортировок, чтобы они работали корректно? В коде, который сейчас отсылаю пытался сделать один стейт для всех сортировок, но они работают по отдельности, поэтому решение неверно. Надеюсь поможете с вопросом
P.S. Я знаю, что можно делать фильтрацию массива с базы данных, но хотелось бы решить проблему на которую напоролся уже

App.js:

```
const dataClone = {
    [
      title: 'Pepperhino',
      image: ...,
      popularity: 25,
    ]
    ...
}
const [isRender, setIsRender] = useState(dataClone)
const [value, setValue] = useState('')

const filterByTitle = dataClone.filter(item => {
  return item.title.toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase())
})

function cardsRender(func) {
  return func.map(({...item}, index) =>
      <Card
          key = {index}
          {...item}
      />
  )
}

<div className="App">
    <div className="wrapper">
            <Header
                setValue= {id => setValue(id)}
                filterByTitle = {filterByTitle}
                dataClone={dataClone}
            />
            <Sorting
                setIsRender={obj => setIsRender(obj)}
                dataClone={dataClone}
            />
    <div className="menu">
      {cardsRender(filterByTitle && isRender)}
    </div>
</div>
```

Поиск по названию в Header.jsx:

```
const Header = ({setValue}) => {

return (
    <div>
        <form className="header">
            <div className="search">
                <img src="/images/search.png" />
                <input type={"text"} placeholder="Поиск..." onChange={(e) => setValue(e.target.value)}/>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
);
};
```

И поиск по популярности/алфавиту в Sorting.jsx:

```
const Sorting = ({dataClone, setIsRender}) => {

function sortByField(field = '') {
    return field === 'popularity' ? setIsRender(dataClone.sort((a, b) => a[field] < b[field] ? 1 : -1)) :
        setIsRender(dataClone.sort((a, b) => a[field] < b[field] ? -1 : 1))
}

return (
    <div className="sorting">
        <ol id="right">
            <p>Сортировать по:</p>
            <li><button onClick={() => sortByField('popularity')}>Популярности</button></li>
            <li><button onClick={() => sortByField('price')}>Цене (по возрастанию)</button></li>
            <li><button onClick={() => sortByField('title')}>Алфавиту</button></li>
        </ol>
    </div>
);
};
```

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что вы хотите организовать многоуровневую сортировку, условно, сначала по популярности, далее сортируем по цене(допустим) и что бы сортировка по популярности не менялась?

Comment: Да, всё верно!!

Comment: У вас 1 стейт под ваши данные `isRender`. Ваш вопрос к React не имеет прямого отношения и решается исключительно реализацией функции на javascript. Что бы сделать, надо определить порядок сортировки, придумать кнопку сброса сортировки. Если сортируете по основному полю, то делаете как обычно, если сортируете по второму как то так должно быть `.sort(a,b) => {if (a.popularity - b.popularity === 0) return a.price - b.price; return 0;}` т.е. если популярности равны, сортируем по прайсу, иначе пропускаем. Для третьего аналогичную проверку на 0 для условий 1 и 2.